# SAP Commerce - Custom Validation Constraints

Tags: validation, constraints, sap-commerce-cloud

I need to create some constraints and check product description based some product attribute (in product cockpit).

For example: if product catalog is X and category Y check if description in EN is not null.

I've created a new custom constraint, but i'm not able to get the product model to read the product attributes.
To Create the custom contraint i've followed this link:

https://help.sap.com/viewer/d97b2ab46fde43a78640036ebf68e106/v2005/en-US/c2f5088646aa40f78dc418904040a64b.html

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: I hope you have reloaded the validation engine.

Comment: Yes, I've reloaded the validation engine